# Create a column based on multiple columns for certain rows Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I have the next table in Power BI

| Ubicación.Name | Fecha_entrega__c | Sector_entrante__c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PAD FP.c-1050 | 5/31/2021 | Perforación |
| PAD LAnch.x-2(h) | 4/30/2022 | Terminación |
| PAD LAnch.x-2(h) | 2/28/2022 | Perforación |
| PAD LAnch.x-2(h) | 7/13/2022 | Well Testing |
| PAD de Pozos 1003 | 4/23/2022 | Terminación |
| PAD de Pozos 1003 | 8/11/2022 | Perforación |

I would like to create a column based on the next logic

For a certain group in "Ubicación.Name", for example, "PAD LAnch.x-2(h)", there are three rows of this kind, I want to check whether the newest of these rows, based on "Fecha_entrega__c" column, has in "Sector_entrante__c" column the string "Well Testing". In this case we can see in row 4 which has the newest date of rows 2,3 and 4 (all of them part of "PAD LAnch.x-2(h)") that in column "Sector_entrante__c" it says "Well Testing", so I want a column that gives the number 1 for rows 2,3 and 4. If it didn't have "Well Testing" I would like to give the value 0 for rows 2,3 and 4.

| Ubicación.Name | Fecha_entrega__c | Sector_entrante__c | Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PAD FP.c-1050 | 5/31/2021 | Perforación | 0 |
| PAD LAnch.x-2(h) | 4/30/2022 | Terminación | 1 |
| PAD LAnch.x-2(h) | 2/28/2022 | Perforación | 1 |
| PAD LAnch.x-2(h) | 7/13/2022 | Well Testing | 1 |
| PAD de Pozos 1003 | 4/23/2022 | Terminación | 0 |
| PAD de Pozos 1003 | 8/11/2022 | Perforación | 0 |

Thanks.

The only thing I have been able to do is to use Rank and Filter to identify with numbers which are the newest and oldest of these group

```
RANK Column =
  RANKX(
    FILTER(
      'Form  NQN PAD Handover (3)',
      'Form  NQN PAD Handover (3)'[Ubicación.Name] = EARLIER('Form  NQN PAD Handover (3)'[Ubicación.Name])
    ),
    'Form  NQN PAD Handover (3)'[Fecha_entrega__c],
    ,DESC
  )
```

But I really have no idea how to apply logic to certain groups within columns.

Comment: Paste your sample data in markdown so it can be copied along with expected results. Thanks

Comment: It asks me to index 4 times but it doesn't appear as it is supposed to do with table markdown according to what I searched. If I don't index it appears as a table to copy but it doesn't allow me to edit it, it keeps on asking to index 4 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Column = 
VAR x = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Fecha_entrega__c]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Ubicación.Name]))
VAR y = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Sector_entrante__c]), 'Table'[Fecha_entrega__c] = x, ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Ubicación.Name]))

RETURN IF(y = "Well Testing", 1,0)
```